# .NET Framework Console app installed on VM can't access Azure Key Vault

Tags: .net, azure, azure-keyvault

I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 console application that I'm trying to configure with Azure Key Vault secrets.

I'm using app.config ConfigBuilders to enable Key Vault reads.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>
...
<configBuilders>
  <builders>
    <add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="key-vault-name" vaultUri="https://key-vault-name.vault.azure.net" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>
  </builders>
</configBuilders>
...
<connectionStrings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">
    <add name="DBConnectionString" connectionString="CheckAzureKeyVault"/
</connectionStrings>
```

This works from Visual Studio when run locally.  It also works when deployed to our Test EC2 instance (Windows Server 2016), when run under a Service Account [using Active Directory Integrated Authentication] that has access to the Key Vault.

If I deploy the same compiled files to our Production EC2 (also Windows Server 2016) and run it under the same Service Account, I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Example.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The configBuilder 'AzureKeyVault' failed during Initialization.: One or more errors occurred. (C:\Example.Program.exe.Config line 21) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/xxxx. Exception Message: Tried the following 4 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/xxx. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. MSI ResponseCode: NotFound, Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>404 - Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
 </body>
</html>

Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/xxx. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Visual Studio Token provider file not found at "C:\xxx\tokenprovider.json"
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/xxx. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.

Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/xxx. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Active Directory Integrated Authentication. Access token could not be acquired. Federated service at https://xxx returned error: See inner exception for detail.Inner Exception :  Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (BadRequest).

   at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.<GetAccessTokenAsyncImpl>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.<PreAuthenticate>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.<ProcessHttpRequestAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.<GetSecretsWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__66.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.<GetSecretsAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder.<<GetAllKeys>b__17_0>d.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.AggregateException.Handle(Func`2 predicate)
   at Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder.GetAllKeys()
   at Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder.Initialize(String name, NameValueCollection config)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection.CreateAndInitializeBuilderWithAssert(Type t, ProviderSettings ps)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
   at Example.Program..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Example.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I'm having real trouble determining why it works on our Dev VM running the application in the same way, but not our Prod one.  .NET Framework 4.8 is installed on both, both can connect to the internet.

On the Prod VM, I'm able to successfully run the application if I use PowerShell and log in via the Azure CLI first.  It's only when I try to run it as the Service Account on the Prod VM that it gets the error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The app.config you deployed on the non-working environment really contains a connection string? (As opposed to what the error message says)

Comment: That part of the error message was unaltered, there is no connection string.  I don't think it needs one, as it works on the Dev VM.  Current investigations are showing that AD DS (Active Directory Domain Services) is installed on the Production VM for some reason.  We're going to test removing that and I'll update if that was the problem.  It does seem to be some sort of non-obvious conflict.

Comment: @topher-j Any update for this issue?

Comment: Yes, for this specific error, we were able to determine it was a CNAME entry from a custom domain (the domain listed in the error message "Federated Service at https://xxx") to an AWS ELB.  The server the application was running on for some reason did not like that CNAME. When we added a hosts file entry mapping the domain directly to a domain controller it worked.  We weren't able to solve the root cause of why that CNAME wasn't playing nicely, but we were able to work around it with the hosts file entry.

This is probably a specific error to our environment, but maybe it will help someone.

Comment: @topher-j Thanks for sharing that. Would you mind posting it as an answer? it will help others to see it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific error, we were able to determine it was a CNAME entry from a custom domain (the domain listed in the error message "Federated Service at xxx") to an AWS ELB. The server the application was running on for some reason did not like that CNAME. When we added a hosts file entry mapping the domain directly to a domain controller it worked. We weren't able to solve the root cause of why that CNAME wasn't playing nicely as of yet, but we were able to work around it with the hosts file entry. This is probably a specific error to our environment, but maybe it will help someone.